# Is there anyone can tell me why there only 8 items, although there are 44 items in the html?

Tags: jsoup

I want to extract some information from a website, but the div count returned by the select method is 8, not the actually 44. Why? Here is my program:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import cornerstone.util.URLUtils;

public class Temp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(URLUtils.toURL("http://s.taobao.com/search?q=耳塞"), 3000);
        System.out.println(doc.select("div.col.item.icon-datalink").size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong *per se* with your code. It is accurately counting the number of matching elements in the HTML it sees. The extra 36 elements in your browser are loaded with JavaScript. To prove this to yourself

- View the plain HTML page source (*not* using the browser's DOM inspector), or
- Load the page with JavaScript disabled

Comment: I have a check, the html is loaded one time, not using the java script. And I save the html into a file, parse it from this file, it still return 8 items.

Comment: I don't think your comment conflicts with my answer. I suspect that, however you loaded and saved the HTML to a file, it did not save the JavaScript-altered state of the DOM. My point is that if you want jsoup to see the same state that you see in your browser, you need to execute the same JavaScript that your browser does.

Comment: I'm sure there are 44 div html element in my local html file, but the jsoup staill return the first 8 element.

Comment: Matt's answer is correct. The HTML returned from the server has most of the datalink items in a comment, which needs JS to extract. See http://try.jsoup.org/~tRNNp9OenJShyyqADaQvBDIVYzI